# font indent and align and tab space for MS ttf different in Red Hat Linux

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am facing trouble with indent and align format of pdf generated in Red Hat Linux. I tested with Ubuntu 10.1; it is generating correct format. The font I am using is Trebuchet MS. I put the ttf jar in the class path and used proper font extension, so the PDF is generating very nicely in Ubuntu. But when I tested with Red Hat 5.4 the indent and tab space and align is so different that words and lines are scrambled. I am using encoding technique in ubuntu "cp1252" same jrxml running in Red Hat. Can you suggest any settings?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RedHat 5.4 version supports Jdk 1.5` only for jasper pdf generation with correct font alignment.So setting path to jdk 1.5 solved my font alignment problem.But when i am setting jdk 1.6 alignment gets scrambled.